# Rails - Devise - edit_user_registration_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

with Rails there is the path, edit_user_registration_path to allow users to edit their profile.

I'm setting up my own Account Control to present the user with a better UI to edit their profile etc.. which is routed at /account/profile, /account/notices, etc....

Problem is this URL, /users/edit  still works and takes users to the DEVISE edit page.

How can I have that always go to the new edit page /account/profile

Thanks

Comment: Why not modify the UI of Devise's page?

Comment: I was told that's not what you're supposed to do. and I want to break it up. Profile Photo Edit Page, Cancel Account Page, Password page, etc.. Like Twitter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably the worst part about devise is making a custom edit profile path. The reason for this is when you try to update your resource, it's going to send you back to the default path for editing the user, that is if you get errors.

What I would suggest is that you keep the default users/edit path and then edit assocations, not the actual resources. Otherwise you are going to have to dig into the gem and rewrite the paths of how users are edited.

This is what I did.

In your User model `user.rb`

```
has_one :profile
has_many :notices
```

Then you can have a `notices` and `profiles` controller where you edit those and not the user or the `resource` which is what you made with the devise helpers and will make it harder to customize. Make a hidden_field `f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id` for those forms and it will save the user when you create them and update them etc...

Comment: Thanks Sam, but I'm not able to follow the above. I don't need a profile association before the profile only consists of the devise info. I do what the user to have a Profile Photo Edit Page, Cancel Account Page, Password page, etc.. Like Twitter but don't understand  how to connect the dots, from controller to view, and back to controller if there's an error. mabye you have any example for doing this for the user Password (current, new, new validate)?

Comment: not really :( I just keept devies basic info, email, password, confirmation on as the 'settings' page and then made associations for everything else. Treated profile as an asset, pictures as assets, etc..

Comment: ah interesting. And you're able to display errors on that settings page with flash? How? I was told in the devise google group not to do that, so IDK...

Comment: Yeah, this is probably not the best way to do it but otherwise if you attach attributes to the user model you always need to enter the current password to update changes.

Comment: does this solution require to separate out the Notices and Profile from the User Table? Currently I have defined all of them in my User model.

Answer (score 4):

As of the latest Devise release (specifically [this commit](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/b50fa7459669aad9069068a52cc137479fb9dcb8)), you can now specify a custom path for the edit profile action via `path_names`:

```
devise_for :users, path_names: { edit: 'profile' }
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way is just to create a ProfilesController, and in your routes, just define "resource :profile". Then you just define the "edit" and "update" methods and you're done.

I haven't taken it much further than the basics, but I really don't see the downside, and it's really simple in comparison to anything that's been offered here.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
def update
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

    if update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
      yield resource if block_given?
      if is_flashing_format?
        flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
          :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
        set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
      end
      sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
      respond_with resource, :location => after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource

#Add a conditional redirect depending on where the controller was called from
      if URI(request.referer).path == '/users/edit'
        respond_with resource
      else
        redirect_to after_update_path_for(resource), :flash => { :alert => "Please enter your password" }
      end


    end
  end
```